# How to draw one NSGlyph, that hasn't unicode representation?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use glyph from Apple Symbols font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468699/how-to-use-glyph-from-apple-symbols-font)

I need to draw glyph with name "gid5002" from Apple Symbols font in NSImage. This glyph hasn't unicode representation, so it's seems impossible to construct string that contains it.
I try:

```
NSFont* font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Apple Symbols" size:12.0];
NSGlyph glyph = [font glyphWithName:@"gid5002"]
```

so, now I have that glyph. What next? I think I can't use NSLayoutManager because lack of unicode representation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Construct an `NSBezierPath` with the outline of the glyph, and then fill/stroke the path into your graphics context.

```
NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Apple Symbols" size:12.0];
NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
[path appendBezierPathWithGlyph:[font glyphWithName:@"gid5002"]
                         inFont:font];
// ...
[path stroke];
```